# Layout getting hide with Listview Layout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to show one layout(With TextView) on Top attached with title bar and at immediately bottom of first layout listview layout ...I am getting only listview layout and this layout hiding layoutCommonLikesHeader...

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.randomchat.MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikesHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You both like Love"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutListMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/etCommonInterest"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="eg:- Music,Friend,Old."
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:textStyle="italic"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_above="@+id/Status"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mCheckBox"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:checked="false"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvAddInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Find stranger with common interest."
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />

      </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btStopStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <EditText android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="type message..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btSendText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/form"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is @layoutList and @layoutInterest?

Comment: paste your whole xml file

Comment: i have posted whole code see above i want show everything like above

Answer (score 0):

Modify you **layoutListMain** like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutListMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: Not working i did alreay . i have also another items at bottom of listview

Comment: could you provide full source code so we can easy for help

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
android:layout_above="@+id/layoutList"
```

with

```
android:layout_above="@+id/layoutListMain"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        tools:context="com.example.randomchat.MainActivity" >

        //This layout not showing at the top of listview layout
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
//removed android:layout_above="@+id/layoutListMain"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
           <!-- //This text i want to show in first layout at top-->
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="what is the now on you are like random stranger if or younotthe newoneso"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--//after first layout i want to show this (Dont want to hide first layout with this layout)-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutListMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader" // added
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"
                android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                ></ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i remove  android:layout_above="@+id/layoutListMain" from first linear layout and added android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader" to second linear layout

Comment: Yes its working fine but now problem is that its hiding bottom layouts ,,

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.randomchat.MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fffffp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="what is the now on you are like random stranger if or younotthe newonese"/>



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000k"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml file like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikesHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You both like Love"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutListMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutInterest"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"> <!-- added this line -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            ></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutInterest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etCommonInterest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="eg:- Music,Friend,Old."
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Status"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddInterest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="Find stranger with common interest."
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Status"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btStopStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


        <EditText android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="type message..."
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSendText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/form"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done with following changes ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E5E5E5"
tools:context="com.example.randomchat.MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikesHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You're now chatting with a random stranger. Say hi!"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvCommonLikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You both like Harry"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"/>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCommonLikesHeader"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >
</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutInterest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText 
     android:id="@+id/etCommonInterest"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="eg:- Music,Friend,Old."
     android:textSize="15sp"
     android:visibility="gone"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:paddingTop="10dp"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:textStyle="italic"
     />

 </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutCheckBox"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_above="@+id/Status"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/mCheckBox"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:checked="false"
          android:visibility="gone"/>
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvAddInterest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Find stranger with common interest."
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />

      </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Status"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btStopStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <EditText android:id="@+id/ChatBoxText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="type message..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btSendText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/form"
    android:text="Send"
    android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```